# class on div to give slideshow more height

Tags: html, css

I would like to give the slidehow under "Why choose us" [MySite][1] a height, so the slideshow holds a straight line with the other column, like this:

[![Picture][2]][2]
I hav tried to set the class `.videoHeight: {500px;}`, but the class is not called. Does anybody knows which div class I had to set it on, to make the height fit? I am using the same slideshow on other sides, therefore the height should *only* fits for this slideshow.

```
<div class="pv-40 banner">
    <div class="container clearfix">

        <!-- slideshow start -->
        <!-- ================ -->
        <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- slider revolution start -->
            <!-- ================ -->
            <div class="slider-banner-container videoHeight">
                <div class="slider-banner-boxedwidth">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <!-- slide 1 start -->
                        <!-- ================ -->
                        <li data-transition="random" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500" data-saveperformance="on" data-title="Premium HTML5 Template">

                        <!-- main image -->
                        <img src="images/slider-boxed-slide-1.jpg" alt="slidebg1" data-bgposition="center top"  data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-bgfit="cover">

                        <!-- Transparent Background -->
                        <div class="tp-caption dark-translucent-bg"
                            data-x="center"
                            data-y="bottom"
                            data-speed="600"
                            data-start="0">
                        </div>

                        <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption sfb fadeout text-center large_white"
                            data-x="center"
                            data-y="110"
                            data-speed="500"
                            data-start="1000"
                            data-easing="easeOutQuad">Premium HTML5 Template
                        </div>  

                        <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption sfb fadeout text-center large_white tp-resizeme hidden-xs"
                            data-x="center"
                            data-y="155"
                            data-speed="500"
                            data-start="1300"
                            data-easing="easeOutQuad"><div class="separator light"></div>
                        </div>  

                        <!-- LAYER NR. 3 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption sfb fadeout medium_white text-center hidden-xs"
                            data-x="center"
                            data-y="190"
                            data-speed="500"
                            data-start="1300"
                            data-easing="easeOutQuad"
                            data-endspeed="600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Nesciunt, maiores, aliquid. Repellat eum numquam <br> culpa offici, tenetur fugiat dolorum sapiente...
                        </div>

                        <!-- LAYER NR. 4 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption sfb fadeout small_white text-center hidden-xs"
                            data-x="center"
                            data-y="300"
                            data-speed="500"
                            data-start="1600"
                            data-easing="easeOutQuad"
                            data-endspeed="600"><a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-animated">Read More <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a> <span class="pl-5 pr-5">or</span> <a href="page-contact.html" class="btn btn-default btn-animated">Contact Us <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
                        </div>

                        </li>
                        <!-- slide 1 end -->

                        <!-- slide 2 start -->
                        <!-- ================ -->
                        <li data-transition="random" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500" data-saveperformance="on" data-title="Clean and Simple Design">

                        <!-- main image -->
                        <img src="images/slider-boxed-slide-2.jpg" alt="slidebg2" data-bgposition="center top"  data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-bgfit="cover">

                        <!-- Transparent Background -->
                        <div class="tp-caption dark-translucent-bg"
                            data-x="center"
                            data-y="bottom"
                            data-speed="600"
                            data-start="0">
                        </div>

                        <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption sfb fadeout text-center large_white"
                            data-x="center"
                            data-y="110"
                            data-speed="500"
                            data-start="1000"
                            data-easing="easeOutQuad">Clean and Simple Design
                        </div>  

                        <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption sfb fadeout text-center large_white tp-resizeme hidden-xs"
                            data-x="center"
                            data-y="155"
                            data-speed="500"
                            data-start="1300"
                            data-easing="easeOutQuad"><div class="separator light"></div>
                        </div>  

                        <!-- LAYER NR. 3 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption sfb fadeout medium_white text-center hidden-xs"
                            data-x="center"
                            data-y="190"
                            data-speed="500"
                            data-start="1300"
                            data-easing="easeOutQuad"
                            data-endspeed="600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Nesciunt, maiores, aliquid. Repellat eum numquam <br> culpa offici, tenetur fugiat dolorum sapiente...
                        </div>

                        <!-- LAYER NR. 4 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption sfb fadeout small_white text-center hidden-xs"
                            data-x="center"
                            data-y="300"
                            data-speed="500"
                            data-start="1600"
                            data-easing="easeOutQuad"
                            data-endspeed="600"><a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-animated">Read More <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a> <span class="pl-5 pr-5">or</span> <a href="page-contact.html" class="btn btn-default btn-animated">Contact Us <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
                        </div>

                        </li>
                        <!-- slide 2 end -->
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tp-bannertimer"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- slider revolution end -->

        </div>
        <!-- slideshow end -->

    </div>
</div>
<!-- pv-40 banner end -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS Way**

You need to set a `min-height` for `#accordion-2`.

```css
#accordion-2 {
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

In the above code, I have used two things. I'll explain you why:

1. `min-height` It is always to stick with `min-height` rather than `height` because of the fact that sometimes the content exceeds the `height` of `300px`.
2. `border` I have given a border in order to show you that the `height` of `300px` is right. Without border, the background of the accordion merges with the body's background, and you won't be able to see the difference.

[image: preview]

---

**HTML Solution**

An alternate way is to use the class `pw-20` for the banner instead of `pw-40`:

[image: preview]

Comment: @KrMa I don't think you need to change the class **as well as add the CSS**. So, do only one of the two.

Comment: Thank you again for the answer. I can solve it this way: `<div class="pv-10 banner">
         <div class="container clearfix">
          <!-- slideshow start -->
          <!-- ================ -->
          <div class="slideshow">
           <div class="col-md-6">
           <!-- slider revolution start -->
           <!-- ================ -->
           <div class="slider-banner-container" style="min-height: 250px;">`

Comment: @KrMa Do you wanna add that in the question, but I could see that you have added the `min-height` to the slider container, which might screwup the plugin. That should be dynamic. Try with different layouts (screen sizes) and if it doesn't fail, I guess it is good to go! `:)`

Answer (score -1):

Remove the class `pv-40` from the slideshow, because it's adding you that top padding

Comment: then add a new class name and set the `padding-top` value to `0`